# Avoiding the unwanted motion detection in aforge.net motion detection algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the `Aforge.Net` dll for the motion detection in video.its detecting the all the moments like hair moments,fan moments etc. How to avoid this.

here is my code:

```
VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();

MotionDetector motionDetector = new MotionDetector(new TwoFramesDifferenceDetector(), new BlobCountingObjectsProcessing());

reader.Open(fPath); // here fpath is my video url
reader.ReadVideoFrame();

Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();

motionLevel = motionDetector.ProcessFrame(videoFrame);

motionLevel= Convert.ToDouble(motionLevel.ToString("N10"));

if (motionLevel > alarmLvl)
{
    //do something
}
```

alramLvl is set to 0.02 for the testing purpose 
any suggestions and helps are appreciated.

Comment: It detects motion. So if the sensitivity of the motion detects hair and/or a fan moving, dial up the alarm level

Comment: I have checked that by increasing the alarm level, but it avoids the number of motion detected in the video frame. I want to avoid that fan moments and I need only to detect the object movements in my video like head movement,hand movement etc

Comment: Is the video close up or in a room itself? Does the fan size and the head/hand movement size similar on screen?

Comment: its a sample video which taken in class room while student taking test. I don't think that sizes are same